# How does the branch predictor know if it is incorrect?

Tags: caching, branch, cpu

So I did do a search of this question, but the answer I found I didn't quite understand.

What I understand for a CPU, is that the Instruction Fetch unit solely receives instructions from the Branch Predictor; which it will then go through L1i cache/L2/L3/RAM to find the predicted instruction to execute and then away it goes.

However, the problem I'm having is; how does the branch predictor know whether what it did was correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

*The branch instruction itself is still executed*, i.e., the condition is evaluated and the target determined. For a conditional branch, if both condition and target were both correctly predicted, the predictor would typically be informed so that the state can be updated to strongly taken/not-taken (if the previous state was weakly taken/not-taken).<sup>1</sup>

If the condition or target were incorrectly predicted, the predictor receives the correct information from the execution of the branch instruction, instructions in the mispredicted path are flushed from the pipeline, and fetching restarts at the correct address.

---

<sup>1</sup> It would be possible for the predictor to speculatively update the branch information and correct on misprediction. Speculative update is typical for global history vectors since the information is needed for the next prediction whereas confidence information is not typically needed until a misprediction occurs. The confidence information could be used for selective dynamic predication, reducing checkpointing, prioritizing another thread, reducing power use, etc., but it is typically only used to keep a single event from changing the predicted direction.

Comment: Understood, but how does the predictor do this:

"If the condition or target were incorrectly predicted, the predictor receives the correct information,"

? Where does it get the information that it is correct or not?

Comment: @user3423509 The *execution* of the branch instruction tests the condition, determining whether it was supposed to be taken or not taken; the taken/not-taken *prediction* is carried along with the branch instruction so it can be determined whether the prediction was correct. The target determination is handled similarly, though for instruction address-relative branches this can be calculated early since the constant offset is available after instruction decode (earlier with a classic RISC).

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply. However, I still don't quite understand. What exactly happens in this "branch" instruction. Is it the prediction sequence? How does the unit know whether a prediction was right or not before predicting? Im confused...